# Why did god create bad people?

Tags: shiva, krishna, brahma, creation

I want to praise and appreciate god I want to serve and be devoted to god but bad people start to make me even doubt the existence of god. I cant really fully devote myself to god because of these kind of people.How to protect oneself against bad people and thoughts?
If I am focusing on my work and if someone get their work done by cheating/corruption and they are not getting caught then it really shakes my belief in god.What to do, I need some kind of direction and energy.

Comment: People have free will and some choose to be bad. Some also have negative karma.

Comment: At the outset , God had not created bad people .  Although God is the seed /substratum of anything and everything , yet, Bhagavan  is never an aspect of anything that is bad,  as  in (**Gita 7.(8-11)**).Lord is never a source of any desire that is forbidden by dharma. Such adharmic forces (that part of Ignorance) aren't the instrument of God.Regarding those who are **fully devoted** to God , are by very nature sarva-sankalpa-sanyasi ( they won't have any worldly seeking whatsoever). So, they aren't bound by even survival instinct , An Instinct to get liberated /surrender is fundamental in them

Comment: So for a fully devoted , there is no question of any protection from bad people etc. (Vasudevam sarvam ithi , sa Mahatma durlabaha -It is tough to find one such fully devoted mahatma).
Devotion has extensive gradations. One should know what category of devotee they are. Avoiding bad people by (upeksha ) ignoring them as suggested by Patanjali Rishi or to fight with them  in a dharmik way are the possible alternative s

Comment: The infinite has infinite combinations and good and bad are human polarities.

Comment: @Athrey Your attempt to distance the Saguna Bhagavana from evil tendencies sounds as if it has been taken from a Christian text. Brahman is above ALL dualities, which also includes the duality of dharma-adharma. If it hadn't been so, then the line सर्वधर्मान् परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज becomes useless.

Comment: There is an emphatic inclusion of the adjective punyo in Gita 7.9( **punyo gandhah** prithivyam cha ) which according to Sri Shankara s commentary , +ve adjective is extensible to other Panchabhootas in previous verses also.Here it is said that pure fragnance is the substratum of earth(unlike usual understanding , that fragnance being attribute of earth).Bad fragrance overlays the pure fragnance , due to neiscience(avarana , vikshepa) that is anadi. No doubt it also emerges from/and is part of God .

Comment: **dharma aviruddho bhuteshu kamosmi** (7.11) says Gita .which means adharmic desires aren't expressive of divine. (Not sure if you suspect this to be a Christian interpolation !) Panchadashi and Advaita prakarana granthas say shuddha sattva of prakriti is the upadhi of Ishwara, So Ishwara is omniscient, that contains (good and bad) and knows them all.

Comment: Cosmic and Moral order ( is idea of rta) that sustains the manifestation.Gitacharya God upholds and sustains this order, and sets things right , does not let go of fallen order unconcerned  ,. This Avatara of God is not beyond good and evil and takes the responsibility over righteousness.(Yada Yada hi dharmasya).. When it comes to सर्वधर्मान् परित्यज्य , it is beyond good and evil and the order of reality changes

Comment: so u can think u r good

Comment: Guys please use search option before asking any question. I have been noticing many of you simply post the question without even searching. Questions like this are posted several times already.

Comment: Does [Why did god create us even though he knew that we will partake in adharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26063/647) answer your question?

Comment: It is people who choose whether to be Good or Bad, God just approves it

Comment: Does [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/54247/20968) answer your question.?

Comment: No, I mean what kind of sports is this at least be it a healthy sport where everyone are healthy and happy@SriShivaCharañkeDāsVishñu